# Error with configuring Phabricator with Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, phabricator

I'm installing Phabricator on CentOS7 using Nginx. I followed the nginx config from their site. When I try to access the url:port`pha.mysite.com` in browser, I got `File not found` message on browser and found error message in nginx log file :

**Error Message in Nginx** :

```
[error] 6433#0: *499 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 223.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: pha.mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "pha.mysite.com"

[crit] 6433#0: *499 stat() "/root/pha/phabricator/webroot/favicon.ico" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 223.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: pha.mysite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "pha.mysite.com", referrer: "http://pha.mysite.com/"
```

I also checked if `php-fpm` is listening on port `9000` :

```
$ netstat -nap | grep 9000
tcp  0  0 127.0.0.1:9000  0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      7884/php-fpm: maste
```

**Here is my nginx conf** :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pha.mysite.com;
    root        /root/pha/phabricator/webroot;

    location / {
            index index.php;
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?__path__=/$1 last;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
            try_files $uri =204;
    }

    location /index.php {
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;

            #required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
            fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

            #variables to make the $_SERVER populate in PHP
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

            fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

            fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

**Here is my php-fpm www.conf snippet** :

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

I've also set `777` for phabricator's webroot :

```
[root@centos phabricator]# ls -l
... ...
drwxrwxrwx  3 nginx nginx  4096 Nov 12 16:33 webroot
```

Is there any idea for troubleshooting this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the tag wiki for the [tag:code-review] tag. Do note that troubleshooting/debugging is off-topic on [codereview.se] though. Good luck!

Comment: Does the file `/root/pha/phabricator/webroot/index.php` exist?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, the file does exist.